# Why docker container exits in detached mode?

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get -y install wget nano tar unzip bzip2

RUN apt-get -y install python-pip
RUN pip install --upgrade pip

RUN mkdir /opt/docker/
COPY templates/cclib.zip /opt/docker/
RUN cd /opt/docker/ && unzip cclib.zip
RUN cd /opt/docker/cclib && pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY templates/entrypoint.sh /opt/entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /opt/entrypoint.sh

CMD /opt/entrypoint.sh
```

And entrypoint.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo $ENV1
echo $ENV2
echo $ENV3

echo "Starting."
cd /opt/docker/cclib/manuals && python reindex.py $ENV1 $ENV2 $ENV3
echo "Finished."
```

I launch the container with the following command:

```
docker run -dti --name container --env ENV1="-b Value" --env ENV2="-y 
Value" --env ENV3="-t Value" rmparser:v1
```

In detached mode, the container exits, but the script does not complete its work, **docker logs** shows that the script has no completion status or errors. The **docker inspect** command did not help (container has exit status 0). I tried to run the container in foreground mode (without **-d** option), and the script worked fine, finished with status 0 and no errors.
Also i tried to enter the container via **docker attach** and run the script, it worked as it should.

**Update:**

The program ends correctly. But I would like to understand why the log is not written completely in detached mode.

Comment: How come you're using your entrypoint as your CMD? Your issue may be there, try: `ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/entrypoint.sh"]`. I feel like your way should work anyway because ubuntu dockers entrypoint is just `/bin/sh -c` but still it's wrong

Comment: @GeorgeAppleton, I tried, it did not help. ENTRYPOINT and CMD give the same effect if only one of them is defined.

Comment: Well that's not really quite true, they have the same effect under default conditions which isn't always the case. Use CMD if you potentially want to change the executable, otherwise use ENTRYPOINT